# phpmailer - Is it possible to call message body using a specfied path to a html file?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I was wondering if there is a possibility to call the message body from a path specified instead of a php variable.
Instead of this,

```
$mail->Body=$body;
```

is there any way like specifying a path like this
('/mydomain/index.html')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes – just read the file yourself:

```
$mail->Body = file_get_contents('/mydomain/index.html');
```

Comment: but i m gonna go with php variable, since i cant call any variables inside the html using this method

Comment: or is there any way to do that also ?

Comment: Yes - look at using `include` (which can be slightly tricky), or running your PHP inside an [output buffer](https://www.php.net/ob_start). Ultimately anything that returns a string can be passed to `Body`.